# Why can a constructor invoke a method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to Javascript and come from a classical OOP background.

One thing I noticed recently is that a constructor can invoke a method in Javascript, for example, `Object.getPrototypeOf()`. I'm wondering how the method is defined in the constructor in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both classes and functions are also objects, and objects can have arbitrary key-value pairs set on them. It's not entirely common, and it's sometimes a code smell, but it's possible. Values can also be functions, so if you access a property which is a function, you can call it:

```js
function FooFunc(arg) {
  this.name = arg;
}
FooFunc.prop1 = 'val';
FooFunc.prop2 = () => console.log('prop2 invoked');
FooFunc.prop2();

class FooClass {
  constructor(arg) {
    this.name = arg;
  }
}
FooClass.prop2 = () => console.log('prop2 invoked');
FooClass.prop2();

// Classes can also do this with the static keyword:
class FooClass2 {
  constructor(arg) {
    this.name = arg;
  }
  static prop2() {
    console.log('prop2 invoked');
  }
}
FooClass2.prop2();

// None of this interfers with creating and using normal instances:
const foo = new FooClass('bob');
console.log(foo.name);
```